# angular2 sub navigation bar, routing, and path parameters

Tags: angular

I have the following URLs:

business/details/contacts/:id

business/details/account/:id

business/details/address/:id

and in my routing I have the following:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'details',
        component: BusinessDetailsComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'contacts/:id',
                component: BusinessContactDetailsComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'account/:id',
                component: BusinessAccountDetailsComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'address/:id',
                component: BusinessAddressDetailsComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

The idea is that the BusinessDetailsComponent has a navigation bar to navigate between the three pages.

My problem is that the navigation bar in the parent needs the id from the child routes. I have tried to get this from the BusinessDetailsComponent using the code below, but this doesn't work. It works in the children, but not in the parent. Does anyone have any ideas?

```js
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            console.log(params);
        });   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I had to do the following hack:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // This is a hack that I don't like - need to find a better way!
    if (this.route.children != null) {
        this.route.children[0].params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            this.id = params['id'];
        });
    }
}
```